# LoadLibrary() fails with error 1114: "A DLL initialization routine failed" for Users

Tags: visual-c++, loadlibrary

I have a situation where LoadLibrary() fails with error 1114, but only fails when user that is logged in is part of the "User" group.  Works just fine for "Administrators" and "Power Users".  I can also run it just fine if I start application as "Run As" Administrator or power user

I can step through some of the code, but can not make any changes to it (at least not any changes that can be rolled out to the field), so unfortunately the solution has to be external to the application.

So far I tried to give full access to directory (and containing files) where all the exes and dlls to User group without success.  Next I started looking into Group Policy, but before I go in modifying a bunch of stuff, i thought Id run it by this community.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Use Sysinternals (now a division of Microsoft) Process Monitor or RohitAB API Monitor, see exactly what calls are failing and what the arguments are (you can see registry paths, filenames, etc)

Answer (score 1):

A DLL initialization routine failed means that the DllMain of the library returned some anormal status, so it must require administrator to run. If you specify what library you want to load we can provide better answers.